# Insert ALL from a another table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am trying to execute the below statement in one shot. Like we do it using INSERT ALL for inserting rows in a single execution. Is there any way that we can execute the below two statements in a single execution (using INSERT ALL).

```
INSERT
INTO TABLE_a
  (
    COLUMN_1,
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
  )
SELECT 1234, -- unique id for this insertion
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_9=1;
INSERT
INTO TABLE_a
  (
    COLUMN_1,
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
  )
SELECT 1235, -- unique id for this insertion
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_9=2;
```

Comment: What's this got to do with INSERT ALL? (Hint: NOTHING!) You can do this easily in a single INSERT statement: keep just the first statement, but change the WHERE clause to read `WHERE COLUMN_9 IN (1, 2)`

Comment: My bad, my example is wrong. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use [in clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm) to collect both Id 1 and 2

and use [decode](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) to differ between 1234 and 1235:

```
INSERT
INTO TABLE_a
  (
    COLUMN_1,
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
  )
SELECT decode(COLUMN_9,1,1234,2,1235),
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_9 in (1,2);
```

Comment: you are missing the different value for column_1 depending on the different values of column_9

Answer (score 0):

Why not use OR condition ? Try this if it works for you

```
INSERT
INTO TABLE_a
  (
    COLUMN_1,
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
  )
SELECT CASE WHEN COLUMN_9 = 1 THEN 1234 WHEN COLUMN_9 = 2 THEN 1235 END,
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_9=1 OR COLUMN_9=2;
```

Using **[DECODE()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)** function as suggested by @Chris

```
INSERT
INTO TABLE_a
  (
    COLUMN_1,
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
  )
SELECT DECODE(COLUMN_9,1,1234,2,1235)
    COLUMN_2,
    COLUMN_3,
    COLUMN_4,
    COLUMN_5,
    COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7,
    COLUMN_8
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_9=1 OR COLUMN_9=2;
```

Comment: My bad, my example is wrong. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Hareesh.check edited answer.. you can use CASE WHEN statement to insert desired values in TABLE_A column_1 as per value in Column_9 of TABLE_B i.e. for 1 or 2 then 1234 and 1235 respectively gets inserted.

Comment: Also only one SELECT statement is required , unique id insertion is handled by CASE statement

Comment: you may also use the DECODE-Function in oracle: DECODE(column_name, value1, ret_value1, value2, retvalue2, defaultvalue) . DECODE can handle up to 255(?) values. Works with integers, chars and everything

Comment: @Chriz thanks for sharing.. I am into SQL Server .. didnt know about DECODE()function.. nice to learn something new now and than.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a union query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_a (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4, COLUMN_5, COLUMN_6,
    COLUMN_7, COLUMN_8)
SELECT
    1234, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4, COLUMN_5, COLUMN_6, COLUMN_7, COLUMN_8
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_9 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    1235, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4, COLUMN_5, COLUMN_6, COLUMN_7, COLUMN_8
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_9 = 2
```

This approach has one noticeable advantage over your original approach.  With this answer, the entire insert is happening in a single statement.

Comment: My bad, my example is wrong. I have updated the question.

Comment: If there are like 5 select statements is that still be fine, having union all in between the select statements?

Comment: Yes, you may union together as many as you need.  Oracle may impose a limitation, but it likely would not happen at 5, assuming each of those 5 selects is not massive or takes a really long time.

Comment: This solution also has the noticeable **dis**advantage, compared to the DECODE, or possibly CASE, solution, that it reads `TABLE_B` twice (or five times, if the OP needs to do this for five different values in `COLUMN_9`).